# Uninitialized Constant for a Rails Services Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app/services directory, I have a file called video_converter.rb.

In that file, I've defined it such that:

```
class VideoConverter
end
```

I go into the rails console and run:

```
VideoConverter.const_defined?
```

And it returns a NameError: Uninitialized Constant VideoConverter.  Did you mean VideoProject (which is the name of the rails project).

I've double and triple checked the spelling, and I don't see a typo, so I'm not sure why rails isn't able to find this constant.  I even ran

```
reload!
```

on the rails console, and still uninitialized.

I am following this tutorial:
https://dev.to/davidcolbyatx/building-a-video-converter-with-rails-6-and-ffmpeg-5e88

I am at the step where we add a background job.  instead of the expected automatic transcoding, I get the uninitialized constant error.

Please advice.

Comment: Are you on Rails 6?

Comment: Everything inside `app/` folder is autoloaded so It should work. Did you try closing and then reopening the `rails console`?

Comment: Yes.  even quit rails and restarted the server to try from that side.  Hmm.  Should I post a Github repo?

Comment: try `bin/spring stop`, it will force Spring to load your app.

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I've been having trouble with spring lately for some reason.

Comment: That's great, please mark the comment as useful, so as to help others.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add code in your app path config/application.rb:

```
config.autoload_paths += [config.root.join('app')]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).